# About monads and LINQ

Tags: linq, haskell, monads

I stumbled upon some statements suggesting that LINQ is powered by monads.

Several C# programmers have asked what a monad is and how it's like LINQ. But I'm a Haskell programmer, and I'm asking what LINQ is and how it's like having monads.

The little I know about LINQ is that it lets you write arbitrary SQL in the middle of your C# code. I'm told it's meant to be possible to implement LINQ for other datatypes, but I've never seen it done. Presumably that's the part where things get interesting. (?)

Any comments or helpful reading would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to read up on LINQ. It's definitely not "letting you write arbitrary SQL in the middle of your C# code".

Comment: Mostly, this is about [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) doing the same thing as `(>>=)`; if you can read generics, their types are the same. And then, the `from` and `select` statements become more or less a strange version of do-notation (there is even a [`let` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx)).

Comment: hmm there might be something to this question (what linq is and how it realtes to monads is certianly objective and not overly broad), maybe its a better fit for PSE tho?

Comment: Its convoluted but you can sort of get there http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/monads-in-c-4-linq-loves-monads.html

Comment: in haskell terms then linq to objects is the list monad